# Java - Get git directory list

Tags: java, git, directory, bitbucket-server

We recently changed from [svn](/questions/tagged/svn) to [git](/questions/tagged/git).
Now I have to change a zip-generator which needs a directory list.

With [svn](/questions/tagged/svn) it was very easy but what is the best way in [java](/questions/tagged/java) to get a list of directories in a specific path?

I tried with the `stash-api` but didn't get an usable result.

Thanks for helping.

Edit:
The structure on [git](/questions/tagged/git) looks like this.
Now I need the directories 1.0.0 - 1.1.1 in [java](/questions/tagged/java) to work with.

├── project
  │   ├── database
  │   │   ├── scripts
  │   │   │ ├── 1.0.0
  │   │   │ ├── 1.0.1
  │   │   │ ├── 1.1.0
  │   │   │ └── 1.1.1

Edit2:

Old way

```
    File file = new File(this.source);
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
```

this.source = path to svn folder

Comment: You mean to say you did this programatically with SVN?

Comment: I used Java to get the list from SVN and it wasn't a problem.
But I need the directory list from the Git remote now

Comment: How did you do that with svn? Via an executed command?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do this via Java instead of just using some kind of shell script with git's built-in command line interface?

Comment: Have you tried looking at [JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/) ?

Comment: I tried with JGit but it only worked local. How can I do It on the remote?

Comment: Also see: [Java Client to Connect to Stash Repository](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24963084/2936460).

Comment: @0riginal Why do you need to do it on the remote? Surely your local repository is as valid a repository as the remote if you've pulled?