# Java Client to Connect to Stash Repository

Tags: java, git, maven-plugin, bitbucket-server

I am trying to programatically connect to a STASH repository from a Java class. I have had a look and I cannot find any Java clients to do this. Has anyone come across any?

The reason I want to connect to a STASH repository is that I am writing a Maven plugin that will go to a Git repository in STASH and return a list of commits and then Jiras for a given tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/). First google result for jgit.

Comment: Thanks Elliot... Not sure how I didn't see this... All of my questions on Google where around STASH and I didn't think about just looking for Git

Comment: This also looks promising: https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/stash-java-client

Comment: @JanZyka and yet, after 1 year they still don't publish it to maven central

Answer (score 0):

*(Consolidating two answers given in comments as a Community Wiki answer)*

First of all, there's [JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/):

> JGit is an EDL (new-style BSD) licensed, lightweight, pure Java library implementing the Git version control system.

And then there's the [Stash Java Client](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/stash-java-client):

> The Stash Java Client, is a small, light-weight Java library that can be used to interface with a Stash instance via its REST API.

Comment: stash java client doesn't have any builds available so it is mostly useless

Comment: @krzyk Please feel free to edit this (cw) answer as you see fit; I was only consolidating two comments as an answer, since comments are not as solid as answers.